# Java shortcut in VSCode to open JavaDocs

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In Intellij the shortcut for showing official Javadoc is `CTRL+q`.
Any shortcut to do this in VSCode?

Comment: Ctrl+shift+p -> select javadoc generator

Comment: Press Ctrl and click a function or class can go into its `.class` file. If there're comments before code, the extension **Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat** will get them and when you hover up the function or class in `.java` file, the comment or we can call them docs will be displayed in a block, so when you go into .class, are there any comments or docs there?

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension calls

[Docs View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.docs-view)
which show you the docs in separate vs code window

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to view the Java documentation in Visual Studio Code to you can do it by the following ways:

1. mouse hover elements which you want to lookup
2. after short version appears, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key twice (if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key once, the long version documentation appears as long as you hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key)

**`NOTE:`**  if it didn't work you need to install the java extension path in your visual studio code which the extension id is: `@id:vscjava.vscode-java-pack`

[image: visual studio code with Java code and related Java extension]

Comment: unfortunately pressing ctrl once or twice doesn't show anything. my Vscode versoin is 1.51. @mustafa poya did you change something in the configuration or the settings of ur vscode to enable documentation?

Comment: @MahmoudEzzEldin try install this extension: `@id:vscjava.vscode-java-pack` and then you can view the documentation of every Java Class you want

Answer (score 1):

VS Code have such capability but you may need to set a keyboard shortcut first. First go to the configure page:

[image]

Search `Show Definition Preview Hover`, you will see it, and just set a shortcut whatever you want:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to view documentation in a separate panel, there is an extension called [Docs View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.docs-view). Simply set shortcuts for `docsView.documentation.focus` and `workbench.action.togglePanel`, position the cursor over the class, attribute or method and press the shortcut. Other useful commands are `editor.action.showHover` and `editor.action.showDefinitionPreviewHover`.

[image: docs-view-preview]